# Update a filed using sharepoint workflow 2013 without affecting its modified date & version

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, workflow-manager

I am working on a sharepoint online classic team site. and i have a custom list which contain a field named "Formatted ID" , which is formatted as follow "ITEMID-IT", so the field will hold values such as "1-IT", "2-IT", ...."500-IT".

to achieve this i want to create a workflow 2013 which get triggered on item added, to set the formatted id value. but my question is; if i can force the workflow to update/set the "formatted ID" field without affecting the item version or the item modified date? something similar to how "SystemUpdate" works when writing power-shell scripts?

Answer (score 1):

I have done a test in my SharePoint.

I create a workflow 2013 which get triggered on item added, set the formatted id value, it will affect the item version and the item modified date.

There is no method to set the formatted id value without affect the item version or the item modified date.

Comment: same applies here.. but can i benefit from calling http requests from the WF-2013 to do such an update?

Comment: Because the formatted id value has been changed, the item version and the item modified date will be changed.